# how to check if a file is present in htdocs folder of Apache web server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to check if a particular file is present in htdocs folder of my Apache web server with Ajax request. I am new to Ajax. Please let me know if my approach is right.

I am writing the following function in Javascript to perform the above action.

The url I have considered is:"http://film.ts".

```
function checkURL(url){
    var Ajaxhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        Ajaxhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        Ajaxhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    Ajaxhttp.open("HEAD",url,true);
    Ajaxhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (Ajaxhttp.readyState==4 && Ajaxhttp.status == 200){
            data.playoutInfo._playoutUrls[0] = url;
        }
        else if(Ajaxhttp.status == 404){
            data.playoutInfo._playoutUrls[0] = "http://San_Diego_Clip.ts";
        }
    }
    Ajaxhttp.send();  
}
```

With the above code I am getting the status as 200 even if the file does not exist. Please suggest me if I can achieve this by some other means.

Comment: That should work fine. Check that the server isn't returning 200 statuses with the text of a 404 error page due to misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Ajaxhttp.open("GET",url,true);` to issue a GET request. Check the api of `xhr.open` at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest

it's

```
void open(
   DOMString method,
   DOMString url,
   optional boolean async,
   optional DOMString user,
   optional DOMString password
);
```

so , you got 200 all the time for `HEAD` request.

Comment: Why would you get a 200 just because you made a HEAD request? http://jsfiddle.net/pf3KA/

Comment: No, if you want to query options about a server then you make an [OPTIONS request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.2). The purpose of HEAD is to get the HTTP headers that you would get if you made a GET request. This is idea for finding out if a resource exists (e.g. is not a 404) without asking the server to send you the whole resource.

Comment: by the way which browser are you using for debugging ?

Comment: check whether the browser support HEAD for xhr?

Answer (score 0):

In your htdocs folder create three[3] files 1)searchFile.php   2)ajaxreq.php , create a file call it IamAfile.txt.

=inside the searchFile.php=
========Write this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Looking For A File</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="repoter">Content for  class "repoter" Goes Here</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("ajaxreq.php",
  {
    anyFile:"IamAfile.txt"

  },
  function(data,status){
    $(".repoter").html( data ); 
  }
  )
});
</body>
</html>
```

==End of **searchFile.php**==

Now

==inside the ajaxreq.php==
========Write this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['anyFile'])) {
$anyFile=$_POST['anyFile'];//your in need file
$ineedFile=$anyFile;
if (file_exists($ineedFile)) {

//if the in need file is htdocs folder report this

$report="The file is here. Named :  <a href='$ineedFile' >Open The File Here</a>" ;

  }
  else if (!file_exists($ineedFile)) {

//no such in need file report this

$report="No Such File In Mentioned Directory";

  }
 else{
 $report="Sorry Dont Understand your request";
 exit;
 }

 echo $report;
}
?>
```

===================================================End of **ajaxreq.php**=============

Test request

if all files are created in your htdocs copy paste this /searchFile.php into your browser, hit enter . This how i will do it using Jquery Ajax